# Does FLEXLM_TIMEOUT environment variable work with ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-license-manager

In versions of ArcGIS Desktop earlier than 10.0, you could create/set the FLEXLM_TIMEOUT to a higher value for slower connections.  I'm currently trying to troubleshoot a system (one where I have minimal control) with slow connections to the license manager.

I was able to create a FLEXLM_TIMEOUT user variable and fired up ArcMap several times with no timeout error but maybe I'm lucky and the network I'm on is having no issues.

Does anyone know if this environment variable is actually used by ArcGIS (FLEXnet Publisher)?

Comment: Yes it works, though you might have to change users computer settings to make use of it - network installs need admin - http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/16274

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Full Answer is at [How Does OpenLM TIMEOUT for ESRI ArcGIS works](https://openlm.com/blog/how-does-openlm-timeout-for-esri-arcgis-works/) but key part is:

> The timeout mechanism provided by OpenLM for ESRI ArcGIS is based on
> two parameters, “maximum idle time” and threshold. The combination of
> these two parameters provides a good solution for floating licenses
> (FLEXlm features) with both high and small number of licenses. The
> timeout value should be kept minimal (15-20 minutes) for all FLEXlm
> features and user groups